# How to decrease or increase of each textView's value

Tags: java

How to decrease or increase of each textView's value? Here is my code given below.

```
private static int count;
private String stringVal;
TextView po=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.edittext_po);
Button poplus=(Button)findViewById(R.id.poplus);
poplus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private Object Text;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            count = Integer.parseInt(po.getText().toString());
            count ++;
            stringVal =Integer.toString(count);
            po.setText(count);
        }
    }
```

Really appreciate if someone can help!

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: the code is not working